# How to pass an object in query string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, get, associative-array

I see many questions about passing an array as a query string in PHP, and it seems the prevailing way is using brackets as in `key[]=foo&key[]=bar`.

However I cannot find a straight answer about how to send an *object* (or a `key=>value` associative array - same thing) as a query string.

Currently, however I do it is:

**STRING**

`?foo=bar&hello=world`

Then on the server side, I would do:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array['foo']=$_GET['foo'];
$array['hello']=$_GET['hello'];
?>
```

Of course when using `$_POST`, this is very simple with an `ajax` request. Any object you send automatically serializes and isn't a problem.

Is this the best way to handle it, or is there some other standard for sending an **object** in a query string using PHP?

Comment: `?object[foo]=bar&object[hello]=world`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks, that does seem to work. What about sending a an array as one of the `values` as in `?object[foo]=1&object[foo]=2`. That would be the last clarification needed. Thank you!

Comment: `object[foo][]=1&object[foo][]=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an associative array in a form and in the query string:

```
object[foo]=bar&object[hello]=world
```

To build it URL encoded:

```
$data['object']['foo'] = 'bar';
$data['object']['hello'] = 'world';
echo http_build_query($data);
```

Yields:

```
object%5Bfoo%5D=bar&object%5Bhello%5D=world
```

You can go many levels and/or use dynamically added elements.  In general, in text form, it looks just like a PHP array

```
object[foo][more][even more][]
```

Or:

```
object[foo][][more][even more]
```